# What is the checksum value for kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso?

Tags: checksums

Running WinMD5Free v1.20 said it's not matching current 8d8413fe8d7ca81bdab86180e8d5386e

What is the checksum value for kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso?

Comment: The checksum is specified here on [https://kubuntu.org/alternative-downloads/](https://kubuntu.org/alternative-downloads/)

Comment: Yours is correct from `8d8413fe8d7ca81bdab86180e8d5386e *kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso` as found [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/16.04/release/MD5SUMS)

Comment: comes back with no match

Comment: Please run this from terminal `md5sum kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso`

Comment: I don't trust that `WinMD5Free v1.20` mine came back ok using `md5sum` command!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about `WinMD5Free v1.20` but Ubuntu flavoured linux come with the `md5sum` command to check these things. To check please do:

```
md5sum  kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Then compare it to the official MD5SUM [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/xenial/release/MD5SUMS)

I ran mine on `md5sum kubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso` and it corresponded with that found [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/zesty/release/MD5SUMS)

Since your testing it on Windows use the `CertUtil` inbuilt tool like so:

```
CertUtil -hashfile C:\TEMP\MyDataFile.iso MD5
```

More:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: I was trying to check before running. Only have Windows right now.

Comment: Does your windows have `bash shell`?

Comment: sorry to say no. that will change soon. your reading matched my of I'm going for it

Comment: Windows has this `CertUtil` utility used like this `CertUtil -hashfile C:\TEMP\MyDataFile.iso MD5` try that

Comment: So does this mean good to go?E:\Kubuntu 16.04.3 LTS>CertUtil -hashfile kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso MD5
MD5 hash of file kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso:
8d 84 13 fe 8d 7c a8 1b da b8 61 80 e8 d5 38 6e
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.

Comment: Yep bro your good to go, have fun and welcome to Linux and Ubuntu in particular.

Comment: George, I was going with v16 due to it being more stable. I have been away from UNIX for 14 yrs. Did start in 1987 Looking forward to getting to know  Kubuntu. Thank you for all your help

Comment: I am sticking with `16` till `18` shows up next year :)